# Unable to execute stored procedure in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have an application that uses EF6. I need to execute the stored procedure, so I do the following:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
{                      
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.ExampleStoredProcedure", conn)
    {
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", "parameterValue"));
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = cmd };

    durations = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(durations);                        
}
```

My connection string from Web.config is:

```
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer\DEV;initial catalog=MyApp;User Id=UserId;Password=password123;Application Name=Connection Secured;integrated security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

When the code above runs I get an exception:

```
Login failed for user 'UserId'.
```

The exception also contains the SQL error code: **18456**.
I confirmed that user has full access to this SQL server, database, instance and stored procedure by logging into SQL server with this SQL account and running the stored procedure in question.

I also tried defining a new SqlConnection object:

```
 SqlConnection newCon = new SqlConnection("Server=MyServer\\DEV;Database=MyApp;User Id=UserId;Password = password123;");
```

and executing the stored procedure against it - it worked this time. So I do have a workaround, but would like to use the context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString object to avoid having multiple connection string in web.config file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the value of `context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString`.

Comment: Does your UserID user have proper permissions to Execute stored procedures on the db?

Comment: @Chad Yes, from my question text: "I confirmed that user has full access to this SQL server, database, instance and stored procedure by logging into SQL server with this SQL account and running the stored procedure in question."

Comment: @Kyle here it is: data source=MyServer\DEV;initial catalog=MyApp;User Id=UserId;Application Name=Connection Secured;integrated security=false;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework

Comment: Have you tried to make entity connection the same as the second one and see if it works ?

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj I have not, the connection string for entities that I have in web.config has been generated when I added my data model in Visual Studio 2015 and I have not modified it in any way.

Comment: Please just replace it for a moment and see if it works because sometimes it is not well-generated, if thats not the case we can see another option

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj I can't just replace the connection sting in web.config with the one I define in new SqlConnection object. It appears that Entity Framework expects a certain format of the connection string and "Server=MyServer\\DEV;Database=MyApp;User Id=UserId;Password = password123;" is not in that format.

Comment: Hmm I am not sure for that but I am not using the one entity framework generates. Here is an example what I am using `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password='password';Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Comment: @RajmondBurgaj That's interesting. I am getting System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'data source'.' when I use the connection string in that format. Are you using dbcontext or objectcontext?
According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404268/keyword-not-supported-data-source you do need metadata element in the connection string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146576/discussion-between-rajmond-burgaj-and-myroslav).

Comment: Sorry to let you know I am using code first approach, if you are not using code first approach then you are right. Please lets continue in chat for more

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is by design for security reasons as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467335/connectionstring-loses-password-after-connection-open) answer to a question suggested. I added 
`Persist Security Info=True` to connection string that Entity Framework generated in web.config file and I was able to reuse **context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString** to execute the stored procedure with ADO.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) open a separate connection for this.  You can use the same connection that the DbContext uses.

Just open the connection (it will be closed when the DbContext is disposed) and cast it to SqlConnection. eg

```
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
        var con = (SqlConnection)db.Database.Connection;
```