# How to get connectionString from EF Core 2.0 DbContext

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In EF6 works this code:

```
    public string GetConnectionString(DbContext ctx)
    {
        ObjectContext _objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext;
        if (_objectContext?.Connection != null)
        {
            EntityConnection entityConnection = _objectContext.Connection as EntityConnection;
            return entityConnection?.StoreConnection?.ConnectionString;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

How to do it in EF Core 2.0 ?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
var connectionString = ctx.Database.GetDbConnection().ConnectionString;
```

with EF Core 5:

```
   var connectionString = ctx.Database.GetConnectionString();
```

Comment: thanks, found it in nuget package: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`

Comment: But it doesn't include the password.

Comment: @Khodaie, the password will be in there [until a connection is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467335/connectionstring-loses-password-after-connection-open), unless you use Persist Security Info = true in your connection string. You could fetch the connection string in your context's constructor and store it in a private field, that way you have access to it later on. However, that defeats some of the added security, so be careful.

Comment: In Ef Core 2.2 you need to add using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;